# Batch jobs design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, batch-processing, system-design

I would like to know if there is any design pattern for generic operation that may be part of many projects.

To simplify it let's describe the operation by example:

We have customers that have newspapers subscriptions. How to make sure that 1 day before subscription ends email will be sent (only once) to subscriber with information that subscriptions is comming to an end.

Requirements:

- we need to make sure that email for each such subscriber is sent only once

It may ofcourse have aplication in many other business cases.

Thank you very much for any hints.

Comment: Do you mean exactly once or at least once?

Comment: @PeterCsala ideally exactly once

Comment: According to my knowledge none of the e-mailing protocol supports that.

Comment: Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make sure that 1 day before subscription ends email will be
> sent (only once) to subscriber with information that subscriptions is
> comming to an end.

It can be done with the following actions:

- create some permanent storage, e.g. SQL table where you will have field `IsSentEmail`
- then it is necessary to create some SQL job (e.g. [SQL Server job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver16)) that will be run every day. And then you can send email based on condition `IsSentEmail` and 1 day before subscription ends